# Why is my C++ program's copy constructor called twice?

Tags: c++, oop, copy-constructor

I can't figure out why my output start with "ACCB.." - my expectation was "ACB.."

Why is the copy constructor of `class A` called twice?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
    
using namespace std;
    
class A
{
    int x, y, z;
public:
    A(int x, int y, int z) :x(x), y(y), z(z) { cout << "A"; }
    A(A& a) :x(a.x), y(a.y), z(a.z) { cout << "C"; }
    void sh() { cout << x << y << z; }
};
    
class B
{
    A a;
    int q, r;
public:
    B(A x, int y, int z) : a(x), q(y), r(z) { cout << "B"; }
    void sh() { a.sh(); cout << q << r; }
};
    
int main()
{
    A i(9, 7, 4);
    B b(i, 3, 7);
    b.sh();
}
```

Comment: Another case of a beginner who is surprised C++ defaults to copy by value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your copy constructor is being called 2 times because you are making 2 copies. 1 is being made *implicitly* by the compiler, and 1 is being made *explicitly* in your own code.

In your `B` constructor, its `x` parameter is being passed *by value*. That is an implicit copy being made when `i` in `main()` is assigned to `x`. Then, an explicit copy is made when `x` is passed to the copy constructor of the `a` member of `B`.

You can eliminate the implicit copy by changing the `x` parameter to be passed *by reference* instead.

Also, your `A` copy constructor should be declared as `A(const A& a)`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
    int x, y, z;
public:
    A(int x, int y, int z) :x(x), y(y), z(z) { cout << "A"; }
    A(const A& a) :x(a.x), y(a.y), z(a.z) { cout << "C"; }
    void sh() { cout << x << y << z; }
};

class B {
    A a;
    int q, r;
public:
    B(const A& x, int y, int z) : a(x), q(y), r(z) { cout << "B"; }
    void sh() { a.sh(); cout << q << r; }
};

int main()
{
    A i(9, 7, 4);
    B b(i, 3, 7);
    b.sh();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> *Why copy constructor of class A is called twice?*

Because your `B` constructor takes its first argument (an *object* of `class A`) ***by value*** - so a copy of `i` is made, which is then passed to the constructor.

To prevent this, declare the first argument to the `B` constructor as a **reference** (as in the `A` copy constructor itself):

```cpp
    B(A& x, int y, int z) : a(x), q(y), r(z)
    {
        cout << "B";
    }
```